# Troublesome Frog (AIO Intermediate 2013) 3.x

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-3.x, time-limit-exceeded

Recently I was trying out [this](http://orac.amt.edu.au/cgi-bin/train/problem.pl?problemid=689&set=aio13int) problem and my code got 60% of the marks, with the remaining cases returning TLEs.

> Bazza and Shazza do not like bugs. They wish to clear out all the bugs
>   on their garden fence. They come up with a brilliant idea: they buy
>   some sugar frogs and release them near the fence, letting them eat up
>   all the bugs.
>
> The plan is a great success and the bug infestation is gone. But
>   strangely, they now have a sugar frog infestation. Instead of getting
>   rid of the frogs, Bazza and Shazza decide to set up an obstacle course
>   and watch the frogs jump along it for their enjoyment.
>
> The fence is a series of \$N\$ fence posts of varying heights. Bazza and
>   Shazza will select three fence posts to create the obstacle course,
>   where the middle post is strictly higher than the other two. The frogs
>   are to jump up from the left post to the middle post, then jump down
>   from the middle post to the right post. The three posts do not have to
>   be next to each other as frogs can jump over other fence posts,
>   regardless of the height of those other posts.
>
> The difficulty of an obstacle course is the height of the first jump
>   plus the height of the second jump. The height of a jump is equal to
>   the difference in height between it's two fence posts. Your task is to
>   help Bazza and Shazza find the most difficult obstacle course for the
>   frogs to jump.
>
> **Input**
>   Your program should read from the file. The file will describe
>   a single fence.
>
> The first line of input will contain one integer \$N\$: the number of
>   fence posts. The next \$N\$ lines will each contain one integer \$h_i\$: the
>   height of the ith fence post. You are guaranteed that there will be at
>   least one valid obstacle course: that is, there will be at least one
>   combination of three fence posts where the middle post is strictly
>   higher than the other two.
>
> **Output**
>   Your program should write to the file. Your output file should
>   contain one line with one integer: the greatest difficulty of any
>   possible obstacle course.
>
> **Constraints**
>   To evaluate your solution, the judges will run your
>   program against several different input files. All of these files will
>   adhere to the following bounds:
>
> \$3 \leq N \leq 100,000\$ (the number of fence posts)
>   \$1 \leq h_i \leq 100,000\$ (the height of each post)
>
> As some of the test cases will be quite large,
>   you may need to think about how well your solution scales for larger
>   input values. However, not all the cases will be large. In particular:
>
> For 30% of the marks, \$N \leq 300\$. For an additional 30% of the 
>   marks, \$N \leq 3,000\$. For the remaining 40% of the marks, no special > constraints apply.

Hence, I was wondering if anyone could think of a way to optimize my code (below), or perhaps provide a more elegant, efficient algorithm than the one I am currently using.

Here is my code:

```
infile = open('frogin.txt', 'r')
outfile = open('frogout.txt', 'w')

N = int(infile.readline())

l = []

for i in range(N):
    l.append(int(infile.readline()))

m = 0
#find maximum z-x+z-y such that the middle number z is the largest of x, y, z
for j in range(1, N - 1):
    x = min(l[0: j])
    y = min(l[j + 1:])
    z = l[j]
    if x < z and y < z:
        n = z - x + z - y
        m = n if n > m else m

outfile.write(str(m))

infile.close()
outfile.close()
exit()
```

If you require additional information regarding my solution or the problem, please do comment below.

Answer (score 2):

Without going into the algorithm I see a few things that could be improved upon

1. Use `with open(...) as ...` instead of manually opening and closing
2. Use `max()` instead of the `... if ... else ...` structure
3. Improve naming of your variables, [PEP8](http://pep8online.com/) is a good guideline
4. Use `if __name__ == __main__:`
5. List comprehension at reading input

---

```
def froggin(fences):
    maximum = 0
    for idx in range(1, N - 1):
        left = min(fences[0: idx])
        right = min(fences[idx + 1:])
        middle = fences[idx]

    if left < middle and right < middle:
        new_max = middle - left + middle - right
        maximum = max(new_max, maximum)
    return maximum

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('frogin.txt', 'r') as infile:
        N = int(infile.readline())
        fences = [int(infile.readline()) for _ in range(N)]

    result = froggin(fences)

    with open('frogout.txt', 'w') as frogout:
        frogout.write(str(result))
```

Comment: Hi, can I ask, is using "with open(...)" more efficient than manually opening and closing?

Comment: There is no performance gain using `with open` but this way python will automatically close the file when done. It does look cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> #find maximum z-x+z-y such that the middle number z is the largest of x, y, z
> for j in range(1, N - 1):
>     x = min(l[0: j])
>     y = min(l[j + 1:])
>     z = l[j]
> ```

I find the variable naming a bit counterintuitive: why not name the variables in order and require `x < y > z`?

But more importantly, the two `min` calls between them take \$\Theta(N)\$ time, so the entire loop takes \$\Theta(N^2)\$ time. It would be asymptotically better to pre-calculate lists which give the minimum value in each prefix and suffix, because then the whole thing can be done in time \$\Theta(N)\$.